# Implementing basic library functions in LISP (manually)

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, append

Is there any way by which I can define functions `my_list`, `my_cons`, `my_append` which perform similar function as `list`, `cons` and `append` respectively?

Otherwise where can I find the implementation of these functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my_list and my_append, the solutions are:

```
(defun my_list (&rest arguments)
    `(,@arguments)
)

(defun my_append (a_list an_item)
    `(,@a_list ,an_item)
)

(my_append (my_list 'a 'b 'c) 'd)
```

I'm probably wrong but I dont know any alternative method to make pairs, so an alternative to cons do not seems possible. Still, I'm quite new to the LISP world.

Comment: Can you provide a simple explanation of how the codes work. Please.

Comment: the ` means the next symbol you'll write won't be evaluated. That's how we create the list.
The , means the next symbol must be evaluated. (can only be used after a backquote)
The @ removes the items from a list/pair to enumerate them. (can only be used after a ,)

Comment: and what are `&` and `@`? `&` is reference?

Comment: Sorry, pressed enter too fast. The &rest means variadic parameters. Which means that every arguments are in the arguments variable, in the form of a list.

Comment: Oh great! What abt `cons`? Any similar approach?

Comment: Well, as I said in the solution, I don't think there are any other operators to make pairs instead of cons. These we're useful for list manipulation, but will never result as (cons A B) = (A . B), it will end up as (A B), since B will also be a pair with nothing as the second element.

Comment: can I use list to implement cons?

Comment: No, in LISP, a list is a linked list. An item (the car) pointing on the next pair (cdr). So when you do a list of A B C, the representation is like this (A . (B . ( C . () ))). As you can see, it ends up on an item with an empty list. What cons does is it takes the two items and make a pair with them. In other words, the difference with two items would be: cons: (A . B) list: (A . (B . ()))

Comment: @Alexandre Deschamps : You should give a piece of code in your exemple to use your functions.

Comment: unless i'm missing something, my_list can be much more simply defined with `(defun my_list (&rest args) args)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want your lists to be the same as the onces native to your application, You have to start with some primitive to construct a cons, probably cons or dotted-pair, and something to pull a cons cell apart (car, cadr). The others can be build from that.

If you want to re-implement things that are functionally (pun intended) equivalent, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons#Not_technically_fundamental

Comment: Those are `scheme` implementation. I think common-lisp implementations would be different.

Comment: Yes, but the concepts would still apply

Comment: Yes but can you just show me how `cons` can be implemented without using `list` and `append`? I think the implementations would be tougher.

Comment: The same functions can be defined in CL too, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Roger Nash the only difference in CL is that you would use `(defun <name> (<args>) ...` instead of `(define (<name> <args>) ...`, and you would have to `(funcall z ...` instead of `(z ...`