# Implementation of cons using `list` or `append`

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Is there any way by which `cons` can be implemented in Common LISP using `list`, `append`, `first`, `rest` etc?

In the following code

```
(defun my_list (&rest arguments)
   `(,@arguments) ; Line 1
)
```

What does complete line 1 mean ?

Comment: Duplicate? Are you asking to explain one of the answers in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215373/implementing-basic-library-functions-in-lisp-manually

Comment: why would you do want to do that? CONS is the primitive operation to create a cons cell.

Answer (score 6):

First question:  No, because `cons` is the building block for `list` and `append`, not the other way around.  It is like trying to construct a brick out of houses.

Second question:  The backquote syntax is explained in the CLHS (http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/sec_2-4-6.html).

Stylistic comments:

- It is spelt "Common Lisp".
- Do not use underscores to separate parts of names, but hyphens:  `my-list`.
- Do not let parentheses dangle around.  Your snippet should be formatted like this:

  ```
  (defun my-list (&rest arguments)
    `(,@arguments)) ; Line 1
  ```
- Using the backquote syntax outside of macros is usually not a good idea.  In this case, it is completely superfluous:

  ```
  (defun my-list (&rest arguments)
    arguments)
  ```

Comment: Why would using backquotes syntax outside macros is not a good idea?

Comment: I can't speak for Svante, but IMO, using the extra syntax where it is not necessary is always a bad idea.  In my experience, there are very few times you need a backtick outside of a macro.

Comment: @Alexandre Deschamps: backquotes are always useful when you better view at your s-expressions as kind of templates. There is nothing that ties backquote to macros.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could in theory define `cons` in terms of `list` and `append`, like so:

```
(defun cons (car cdr) (append (list car) cdr))
```

Comment: No, `(cons 1 2)` should return `(1 . 2)`, but your version signals an error instead.

Comment: What Lisp are you using? This works for me in CLisp and Emacs Lisp: `(append (list 1) 2) ==> (1 . 2)`. The [standard](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_append.html) agrees: "The last argument [to `append`] is not copied; it becomes the cdr of the final dotted pair of the concatenation of the preceding lists."

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer for the second question:
for the ,:
if my_symbol = 1
`` `(my_symbol 2 3) = (my_symbol 2 3) ``, but with the ,:

`` `(,my_symbol 2 3) = (1 2 3) ``

The , evaluates the next symbol in a ` statement

Now for the @ (which is a symbol, so it needs the , to be activated)

`` `(,@('a 'b 'c) ('d 'e 'f)) =  ('a 'b 'c ('d 'e 'f) ) ``

`` `(,@('a 'b 'c) ,@('d 'e 'f) ) =  ('a 'b 'c 'd 'e 'f) ``

I hope these examples could help.
So the line 1 is simply extracting the arguments from a list and putting them into another one.

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
(defun cons (a b) '(a . b))
```

Or, if you desperately need to use lists...

```
(defun cons (a b) (first (list '(a . b))))
```

Comment: That won't work. The above code would make (cons 1 2) and (cons 4 5) EQ (as the same identical, read-time created, cons to be returned).